# javascript program works in codepen, but not on any browser I try it on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So lost on what I'm doing wrong, I found this code, works fine in [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZPQGo) as I said, but whenever I try to use it in atom or on chrome, errors keep popping up about the `className` tag, very confused.

```js
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
    var currentSlide = 0;
    var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 10000);

    function nextSlide() {
      slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
      currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
      slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
    }
```

```css
/*
    essential styles:
    these make the slideshow work
        */

#slides {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.showing {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}
/*
    non-essential styles:
    just for appearance; change whatever you want
    */

.slide {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: orange;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: green;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: blue;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(5) {
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<ul id="slides">
  <li class="slide showing">Slide 1</li>
  <li class="slide">Slide 2</li>
  <li class="slide">Slide 3</li>
  <li class="slide">Slide 4</li>
  <li class="slide">Slide 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the error on console?

Comment: and you are loading js after the html code ?

Comment: codepen runs in a browser ... I don't understand the question

Comment: uncaught typing error, can not set property "className" of undefined in google

Comment: the program runs in codepen, but fails to run when i open it from a html file.

Comment: works in the code snippet editor in here

Comment: The code 'technically' is right. Just make sure you are loading the JS after the HTML is loaded so that JS can find the classes it refers to. As mentioned earlier, codepen runs in the browser so the question makes no sense, you are just not loading/calling things in the right way as does codepen. Good luck

Answer (score 4):

That's because [*CodePen*](http://codepen.io/), as well as [*JSFiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/) and probably most other online coding tools, by default wrap the JS-code in a [`document.ready`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) or [`window.load`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/588048/3407923) event-handler (or put the `<script>` inside the `<body>` after the other elements).

On JSFiddle, you can turn that off in the JS-panel, but on CodePen I haven't found a way to do that:
[image]

- "onLoad" is `window.onload`
- "onDomready" is `document.ready`

On your own server (or local machine), if your script is (linked) in the `<head>` and you don't explicitly wrap it in either `window.load` or `document.ready`, your JS-code will be executed before the HTML elements are loaded on the page.
So you get the error, because the code is trying to set the `className` of something that isn't there yet:

> uncaught typing error, can not set property "className" of undefined

If you're using *pure/vanilla JS*, I would go with `window.load`, as you can see from the links above, `document.ready` isn't that widely supported. This is how you use `window.load`:

```
window.onload = function() {
  /*your code*/
};
```